# Done button action of MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using custom MPMoviePlayerViewController.
Like below,

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface customVideoViewController : MPMoviePlayerViewController
{
}

@end
```

I am calling this customVideoViewController class from other class to RUN my video serially in landscape mode, video is running fine but I am not able to catch the action onClick of DONE button of MPMoviePlayerViewController.

Can any one guide me.

this is how I am calling to this view.

```
customVideoPlayerObj = [[customVideoViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:self.url];
[self presentViewController:customVideoPlayerObj animated:YES completion:nil];
[customVideoPlayerObj.moviePlayer play];
```

I need to catch the action for DONE button click of this, how to do this...?

here is the observer for the same

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(doneButtonClick:)
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification
                                                   object:customVideoPlayerObj];
```

but control is not coming in `doneButtonClick`

Comment: in which method are you adding your notification observer?

Comment: @Michael Dautermann in the same method where I am calling this.
also I tried to add observer in customVideoViewController file, but didn't helped

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use *MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification* .

Comment: This is from the Apple online docs[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification] "This notification is not sent when a movie is displaying in fullscreen mode and the user taps Done. The Done button pauses playback and causes the movie player to exit fullscreen mode. To detect this scenario, register for other notifications such as MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification."

Answer (score 1):

MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification  and MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification fired when the movie player exits fullscreen.